# Aurelia unit testing access component's viewModel

Tags: unit-testing, aurelia

I am unit testing one of my components in an Aurelia project. I'd like to access my component's viewModel in my unit test but haven't had any luck so far.

I followed the example available at https://aurelia.io/docs/testing/components#manually-handling-lifecycle but I keep getting `component.viewModel` is `undefined`.

Here is the unit test:

```
describe.only('some basic tests', function() {
    let component, user;

    before(() => {
        user = new User({ id: 100, first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Schmoe", email: 'joe@schmoe.com'});
        user.save();
    });

    beforeEach( () => {
        component = StageComponent
            .withResources('modules/users/user')
            .inView('<user></user>')
            .boundTo( user );
    });

    it('check for ', () => {
        return component.create(bootstrap)
            .then(() => {
                expect(2).to.equal(2);
                return component.viewModel.activate({user: user});
            });

    });

    it('can manually handle lifecycle', () => {

        return component.manuallyHandleLifecycle().create(bootstrap)
            .then(() => component.bind({user: user}))
            .then(() => component.attached())
            .then(() => component.unbind() )
            .then(() => {
                expect(component.viewModel.name).toBe(null);
                return Promise.resolve(true);
        });
    });

    afterEach( () => {
        component.dispose();
    });
});
```

Here is the error I get:

```
1) my aurelia tests
       can manually handle lifecycle:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

[Here](https://github.com/aurelia/testing/blob/0635bade27d270c93cd7e4fe3d8ee1e8051569b0/dist/native-modules/component-tester.js#L54) is the the line that defines the `viewModel` on the `component` object but only if `aurelia.root.controllers.length` is set. I am not sure how to set controllers in my aurelia code or if I need to do so at all.

I guess my question is:
How do I get access to a component's viewModel in my unit tests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get it to work, I had to use `Container`:

```
import { UserCard } from '../../src/modules/users/user-card';
import { Container } from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';


describe.only('some basic tests', function() {
    let component, user;

    before(() => {
        user = new User({ id: 100, first_name: "Bob", last_name: "Schmoe", email: 'joe@schmoe.com'});
        user.save();
    });

    beforeEach(() => {
        container = new Container();
        userCard = container.get( UserCard );
        component = StageComponent
            .withResources('modules/users/user-card')
            .inView('<user-card></user-card>')
            .boundTo( user );
    });

    it('check for ', () => {
        return component.create(bootstrap)
            .then(() => {
                expect(2).to.equal(2);
                return userCard.activate({user: user});
            });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not correct. What you're effectively doing is getting the container to register and instantiate a singleton of your `UserCard` class which the framework then reuses. Normally custom element view models are registered as transient.
You are basically not testing/verifying anything in this test apart from the fact that the container is able to instantiate your view model by calling its constructor. Did you verify the html?

Comment: Please see the last update to my answer. Try that repo and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit #2:

I'd also like to point out that your own answer is essentially the same solution as the one I first proposed in the comments. It is the equivalent of directly instantiating your view model and not verifying whether the component is actually working.

#### Edit:

I tried this locally with a karma+webpack+mocha setup (as webpack is the popular choice nowadays) and there were a few caveats with getting this to work well. I'm not sure what the rest of your setup is, so I cannot tell you precisely where the error was (I could probably point this out if you told me more about your setup).

In any case, here's a working setup with karma+webpack+mocha that properly verifies the binding and rendering:

https://github.com/fkleuver/aurelia-karma-webpack-testing

The test code:

```
import './setup';
import { Greeter } from './../src/greeter';
import { bootstrap } from 'aurelia-bootstrapper';
import { StageComponent, ComponentTester } from 'aurelia-testing';
import { PLATFORM } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { assert } from 'chai';

describe('Greeter', () => {
  let el: HTMLElement;
  let tester: ComponentTester;
  let sut: Greeter;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    tester = StageComponent
      .withResources(PLATFORM.moduleName('greeter'))
      .inView(`<greeter name.bind="name"></greeter>`)
      .manuallyHandleLifecycle();

    await tester.create(bootstrap);
    el = <HTMLElement>tester.element;
    sut = tester.viewModel;
  });

  it('binds correctly', async () => {
    await tester.bind({ name: 'Bob' });

    assert.equal(sut.name, 'Bob');
  });

  it('renders correctly', async () => {
    await tester.bind({ name: 'Bob' });
    await tester.attached();

    assert.equal(el.innerText.trim(), 'Hello, Bob!');
  });
});
```

**greeter.html**

```
<template>
  Hello, ${name}!
</template>
```

**greeter.ts**

```
import { bindable } from 'aurelia-framework';

export class Greeter {
  @bindable()
  public name: string;
}
```

**setup.ts**

```
import 'aurelia-polyfills';
import 'aurelia-loader-webpack';
import { initialize } from 'aurelia-pal-browser';

initialize();
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
const { AureliaPlugin } = require('aurelia-webpack-plugin');
const { resolve } = require('path');

module.exports = function configure(config) {
  const options = {
    frameworks: ['source-map-support', 'mocha'],
    files: ['test/**/*.ts'],
    preprocessors: { ['test/**/*.ts']: ['webpack', 'sourcemap'] },
    webpack: {
      mode: 'development',
      entry: { setup: './test/setup.ts' },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: [
          resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
          resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ]
      },
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        rules: [{
          test: /\.html$/i,
          loader: 'html-loader'
        }, {
          test: /\.ts$/i,
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }]
      },
      plugins: [new AureliaPlugin()]
    },
    singleRun: false,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.browsers && config.browsers[0] === 'ChromeDebugging' ? config.LOG_DEBUG : config.LOG_INFO, // for troubleshooting mode
    mime: { 'text/x-typescript': ['ts'] },
    webpackMiddleware: { stats: 'errors-only' },
    reporters: ['mocha'],
    browsers: config.browsers || ['ChromeHeadless'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeDebugging: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [ '--remote-debugging-port=9333' ]
      }
    }
  };

  config.set(options);
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2018"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start --browsers=ChromeHeadless"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aurelia-bootstrapper": "^2.3.0",
    "aurelia-loader-webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chai": "^4.1.6",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.5",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.0",
    "aurelia-testing": "^1.0.0",
    "aurelia-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "karma": "^3.1.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
    "karma-source-map-support": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "^3.0.5",
    "mocha": "^5.2.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "ts-loader": "^5.2.2",
    "typescript": "^3.1.3",
    "webpack": "^4.23.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10"
  }
}
```

#### Original answer

If you're manually doing the lifecycle, you need to pass in a ViewModel yourself that it can bind to :)

I don't remember exactly what's strictly speaking needed so I'm quite sure there's some redundancy (e.g. one of the two bindingContexts passed in shouldn't be necessary). But this is the general idea:

```
const view = "<div>${msg}</div>";
const bindingContext = { msg: "foo" };
StageComponent
  .withResources(resources/*optional*/)
  .inView(view)
  .boundTo(bindingContext)
  .manuallyHandleLifecycle()
  .create(bootstrap)
  .then(component => {
    component.bind(bindingContext);
  }
  .then(component => {
    component.attached();
  }
  .then(component => {
    expect(component.host.textContent).toEqual("foo");
  }
  .then(component => {
    bindingContext.msg = "bar";
  }
  .then(component => {
    expect(component.host.textContent).toEqual("bar");
  };
```

Needless to say, since you create the view model yourself (the variable `bindingContext` in this example), you can simply access the variable you declared.

Comment: I have resorted to manual lifecycle because I wasn't getting anywhere with the regular one either, i.e. I was getting the same error. Yes, if I recreate the viewModel in my test file then there is no problem. But I should not need to recreate my viewModel in test file. I should be able to get a handle to my actual viewModel in my test code. Also my viewModel is not just a data object. It has several methods that make async API calls to backend to fetch data and modify data. It is really not ideal for me to duplicate my viewModel in my test code.

Comment: There's no need to duplicate your view model. You just need to pass an instance of it to the component tester.
I can't guess all of that based on the code you posted. All I'm seeing is that you're not passing the tester some pieces of information that it needs. If you are passing that information, then you should include that code in your question so people can help you

Comment: To answer your question directly: you may need to use `component.bindingContext` instead of `.viewModel`, but if neither exist then you're not giving it your view model in the first place, so how could it figure that out?

Comment: I included additional code in my code snippet above. I have access to the user object but not to the viewModel. And that is my question how do I include my viewModel or access my viewModel in my unit test?

Comment: The user object **is** the ViewModel. Whatever you bind it to, is the ViewModel. You should also be able to access it via `component.bindingContext` as I said in my previous comment

Comment: The user object *can* be a viewModel but the viewModel is javascript file when creating a component. See https://aurelia.io/docs/fundamentals/components#creating-a-component Read the last sentence of the second paragraph. It refers to the javascript file as the viewModel and the HTML file as the view. Also, note that there are methods in the viewModel (JS file) that I'd like to test. So just the "user" object is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: When you create a custom element by convention, the view is the html file and the view model is the javascript file, indeed. Well, it's not really the javascript file but rather an instance of the class you declared in the javascript file. That is still the class you declared and that is still the view model. It has no special methods (that's sort of the point of the framework). If you're looking for the lifecycle methods, you're probably looking for the View / ViewSlot / Controller. These methods are exposed/encapsulated by the component tester. You're already calling them..

Comment: Never mind what I said above, I realize now that you're looking for the view model instance of the `user` custom element when you're passing in the "app" / parent binding context to be bound to. I'll double check later today when I'm at home and get back to you

Comment: It seems to me what you're doing is correct. I did some debugging and I ran into the same issue. I'm guessing you're using karma-webpack? You need to use the AureliaPlugin inside the karma config. Without that, it will fail to load parts of aurelia (this fails silently) and the Aurelia instance won't start correctly. However I ran into another error with the plugin, which appears at first glance like it's a bug in the karma-webpack-plugin. I'm trying to solve this right now and will let you know when I have